# Add gesture to UIViewController from another Swift file

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I need to register a UIPanGestureRecognizer to my different ViewControllers.

So I have a swift class like this:

```
class SideBar: UIViewController {

func register(mainView: ViewController){
    var swipeRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "swipeGesture:")
    mainView.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRecognizer)
}

func swipeGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    println("swiping...")
}

}
```

and I expect when doing something like this my ViewControllers, I'd get the the swipe message.

```
var sidebar = SideBar()
sidebar.register(self)
```

But it doesn't work, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a reference for sideBar as

```
  var sidebar:SideBar?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sidebar = SideBar()
    sidebar!.register(self)
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Up vote if my answer solved your problem. This is scope related issue.